# crash when multiple time call Google map api to convert cordinates to address in iphone

Tags: iphone, google-maps-api-2

I want to show path between to location and want to show adress for that path.
So i have used following api.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=true
```

and there is minimum 10 location in between to cordinates.So all that 1o time i call this api.But in that it show 'Query limit' in response.So i don't get adress and it crash app.So how can i get adress from given cordinates.

Comment: Why are there 10 locations between those two coordinates?  The API you are calling is Google's reverse-geocode API which is an expensive API (in terms of requests) so Google rate-limits that.  If you just need directions between two points, why not use Google's directions API?

Comment: @JaiGovindani i want to show updates path with location update.How can i do in Direction Api?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by update path - you mean you want to keep recalculating the directions as the user moves? Are you sure? That seems like a very inefficient use of resources (not to mention draining battery/using network).  If you really want to keep reverse-geocoding like that you can try using `CLGeocoder` which is built-in to the iOS SDK and gives you a location/address.